# JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 13 of the JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Tengo un problema con el recibir un archivo JSON de un PHP a un Jquery:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 13 of the JSON data

En mi PHP tengo:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id_parte'])){
$lista_productos = lista_productos('',$conn);
for ($i=0; $i < $lista_productos['count']; $i++) {
    if ($_POST['id_parte'] == $lista_productos[$i]['id_parte']['id']) {
        if ($lista_productos[$i]['status']!=66) {
            $listado = array('id'=>$lista_productos[$i]['id']);
            // $listado = $lista_productos[$i];
            echo json_encode($listado, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Y el javascript es:

```
$.post(".carga_productos_filtro.php",{id_parte:id_parte},
    function(response){

        console.log(response);
        response = JSON.parse(response);


        $('#list_productos_'+id_parte).html("<h2>"+response+"</h2>");
    });
```

Y recibo esto en el `console.log`:

```
{"id":"108"}{"id":"109"}{"id":"110"}{"id":"113"}{"id":"114"}
```

Debería recibir más pero de momento si logro pasar a json esto me doy por satisfecho, ya después le añado mas cosas.

Lo que no entiendo es por qué del error ya que tengo hecho algo parecido de esta misma manera y funciona pero en este caso no, he de añadir que en el otro que lo tengo parecido en el console.log se ve como un array (y de color rosa) en cambio en este se ve como si fuera un variable más (y de color negro) y pues no se puede parsear a JSON.

Los errores ademas de en mi Script me los da tambien en lineas de Jquery

> **jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:27452**,
>
> **jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:28202**,
>
> **jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:77649**,
>
> **jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:79907**;

Ya siento el caso tan largo paro quiero ser claro desde el principio (añadir que utilizo el framework de PHP Smarty).

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe, buena primera pregunta. No sé que función usas para la codificación, pero eso no es JSON; debería ser: `[{"id":"108"},{"id":"109"},{"id":"110"},{"id":"113"},{"id":"114"}]`

Comment: El json que muestras no es válido, lo que tienes ahí son 5 json con lo cual si lo intentas deserializar eso a un json te va a dar error. Puedes comprobarlo en la web https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que estás enviando al navegador varios JSON consecutivos (uno por cada iteración del bucle) en vez de un JSON con los todos los datos que quieres enviar. JSON consecutivos no forman un JSON válido.

Para hacerlo correctamente debes meter todos los datos en una única variable y enviarla una única vez:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id_parte'])) {
    /* Datos a ser enviados al navegador */
    $listado = [];
    $lista_productos = lista_productos('', $conn);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $lista_productos['count']; $i++) {
        if ($_POST['id_parte'] == $lista_productos[$i]['id_parte']['id']) {
            if ($lista_productos[$i]['status'] != 66) {
                /* Agregamos el elemento a la matriz de listados */
                $listado[] = array(
                    'id' => $lista_productos[$i]['id'],
                );
            }
        }
    }
    /* Enviamos todos los datos de manera correcta una única vez */
    echo json_encode($listado, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

Comment: Woo Tienes razón, Ahora funciona bien.
Solo he añadido 
`$listado[] = array(
                    'id' => $lista_productos[$i]['id'],
                );`
y `echo json_encode($listado, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` fuera del bucle, gracias, me acabo de sacar el graduado y aun soy algo Noob, Gracias de nuevo

Comment: De nada, un placer ser de ayuda :) También deberías agregar la definición de la variable como una matriz sin elementos (el `$listado = [];` del principio) para evitar advertencias de variable sin definir (que probablemente estén dejando un rastro en el `error_log` de su servidor web). También te recomiendo que te pases por [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) para conocer el formato más adecuado para facilitar la lectura de tu código.

Comment: Eso está hecho!, he de añadir que no será la la ultima pregunta que haga, y que en el trabajo estoy intentando innovar un poco debido a que aqui trabajan con cosas algo antiguas jaja, Un saludo